# Find applied patches in kernel source tgz from git

Tags: linux, git, version-control, kernel

I have a kernel source code with patches in a tgz archive. Most patches are known in kernel git but I do not know which ones have been integrated. How can I tell which patches have been applied to the source code?

Comment: How did you created patches? And what's your source code and what do you mean apply patches to source code?

Comment: Sorry patches was perhaps the wrong term i mean git commits. How can i check which git commits are applied on a source tree without any .git dir ? Something like import a source archive and check against local git repo which commits are applied.

Comment: You can not check git commits outside the git repo directory. You should move the outside dir as a branch inside of youe git repo directory. Details as the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are copying the source code to the outside of the git repo (let’s call it production environment of your application). And then you want to check whether the latest commit in git repo is applied to your production environment (outside the git repo).

If above situation is what you meet, the direct answer is no. But you can c**hange the production environment as a branch inside the git repo**.

For git repo, we usually use branches to work separately and occurrently. And also sync the branches/works/environments if we need to apply changes among the branches. For your situation, you can work on two branches in your git repo:

- `master` branch: work as the production environment inside your git repo.
- `develop` branch:  develop new changes/features or fix bugs on this branch, when you are ready to apply the changes to `master` branch (production environment), just merge `develop` branch into `master` branch.

Steps for the workflow as below:

Assume, you are only work on `master` branch now, and the commit history as below:

```
…---A---B---C  master
```

Now you can create a d`evelop` branch by `git checkout -b develop`, and then works as this branch (such the commits `D`, `E` and `F` in below graph), the commit history will as below:

```
…---A---B---C  master
             \
              D---E---F   develop
```

When you want to apply the commits from `develop` branch into `master` branch (production environment), then use the commands:

```
git checkout master
git merge develop
```

And the commit history will be (both `master` branch and `develop` branch are point to the latest commit `F`):

```
…---A---B---C---D---E---F  master, develop
```

And for more detail branching model, you can also refer [A successful Git branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).